# SSH config ignoring User parameter on OSX

Tags: macos, ssh, git

My personal ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host officenet
User m.orlandin
Hostname versioning.officenet.prv
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/office_rsa
PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

actually my system username is my nickname "mipnamic" and every time I try to

```
ssh git@officenet
```

it sais: "hi mipnamic"

the last command let me know which git repositories are available to my users, actually on the git server we have 2 different users: mipnamic and m.orlandin

**Why it wouldn't expose the Username indicated in the config file?**

I don't really know what's wrong with this, I sincerely hope in a OS-related bug.

My setup:

```
OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `ssh git@officenet` means that you’re explicitly providing `git` as the username for the remote host, (`officenet`) so the `User m.orlandin` line in your SSH configuration file is ignored. That's the (short) answer to your question.

#### Addendum

I suspect that the public key being sent to the remote server (`officenet`) is associated *on the remote server* with the `mipnamic` account and this is checked by the login shell for the `git` user on the remote server.

You should check which public key you’re offering in the SSH connection by using the `-v` (verbose) option, `ssh -v git@officenet`. Its output should include a line similar to:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mipnamic/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Use `cat` (or any other text file viewer) on your local computer to view the contents of this *public* key. Then, on the remote server, check / modify the corresponding entry in the Git user’s `authorized_keys` file, `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: you were right, was sufficien to `ssh officenet`.